# How do I get a variable from a "higher view" into a "ower view" in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I´m new in SwiftUI and I would know how can I get the variable "Selection" from ContentView into SettingView in my "special" case with **UserDefaults.standard.integer**. I think with @Binding is it not possible, right?

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var Selection = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Picker")
    @State var Detail = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        Button(action: {
            self.Detail.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("click")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $Detail) {
            SettingView(showSheetView: self.$Detail)
        }
        
        Picker("", selection: $Selection) {
            Text("Selection1").tag(0)
            Text("Selection2").tag(1)
            } .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle()).padding(.horizontal, 89)
            .onReceive(Just(Selection)) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set($0, forKey: "Picker")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SettingView: View {
   
    @Binding var showSheetView: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                Text("Test")
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Select something"))
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    self.showSheetView = false
                }) {
                    Text("Ok")
                        .bold()
                        
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call SettingsView?

Comment: I've forgotten it. Now it's in the code.

Comment: And what do you want to access in the SettingsView? Just the selection (Int) or the selected value (String)?

Comment: Yes right just the selection 0 and 1 (Int). A selection should be inserted later and, depending on what was selected in the picker, a different View should be displayed in SettingView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@Binding`:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $Detail) {
    // pass the `Selection` as a Binding
    SettingView(showSheetView: self.$Detail, selection: $Selection)
}
```

```
struct SettingView: View {
    @Binding var showSheetView: Bool
    @Binding var selection: Int // access as a Binding

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Test \(selection)") // use as any other variable
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note: it's generally better to use *lowercase* when naming Swift variables, ie. `selection` and not `Selection`.